# Ansible Script Module Not Interpreting Variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am having an issue with the Ansible script module interpreting a with_items variable.

**vsa_deploy_config/tasks/main.yml:**

```
- name: Create VSA scripts for center
  template:
   src: vsa_deploy.ps1.j2
   dest: "/opt/ansible/roles/vsa_deploy_config/files/{{ item.vsa_hostname }}.ps1"
  when: target == "local"
  with_items:
  - "{{ vsa_center }}"

- name: Deploy VSAs on Center
  script: "files/{{ item.vsa_hostname }}.ps1"
  register: out
  when: target == "win_center"
- debug: var=out
  with_items:
  - "{{ vsa_center }}"
```

**vsa_deploy_config/vars/main.yml:**

```
---
vsa_center:
    - vcsa_hostname: 10.10.10.74
      vcsa_username: administrator@vsphere.local
      vcsa_password: password
      vcsa_datacenter: DataCenter1
      vsa_rdm_lun: 02000000006006bf1d58d25a1020d292f8fcfb22b3554353432d4d
      vsa_hostname: sm01-ct01
      vsa_mgmt_ip: 10.10.10.75
      vsa_mgmt_netmask: 255.255.255.192
      vsa_mgmt_gw: 10.10.10.65
      vsa_mgmt_ns: 10.10.10.92
      vsa_mgmt_pg: SC-MGMT
      vsa_mgmt_moref: Network:network-13
      vsa_iscsi_ip: 192.168.2.1
      vsa_iscsi_netmask: 255.255.255.0
      vsa_iscsi_pg: ISCSI
      vsa_iscsi_moref: Network:network-22
      vsa_mirror_ip: 192.168.5.1
      vsa_mirror_netmask: 255.255.255.0
      vsa_mirror_pg: Mirror
      vsa_mirror_moref: Network:network-23
      esxi_hostname: 10.10.10.72
      esxi_datastore: DS-01
    - vcsa_hostname: 10.10.10.74
      vcsa_username: administrator@vsphere.local
      vcsa_password: password
      vcsa_datacenter: DataCenter1
      vsa_rdm_lun: 02000000006006bf1d58d25dd0210bb356a78344e5554353432d4d 
      vsa_hostname: sm02-ct01
      vsa_mgmt_ip: 10.10.10.76
      vsa_mgmt_netmask: 255.255.255.192
      vsa_mgmt_gw: 10.10.10.65
      vsa_mgmt_ns: 10.10.10.92
      vsa_mgmt_pg: SC-MGMT
      vsa_mgmt_moref: Network:network-13
      vsa_iscsi_ip: 192.168.2.2
      vsa_iscsi_netmask: 255.255.255.0
      vsa_iscsi_pg: ISCSI
      vsa_iscsi_moref: Network:network-22
      vsa_mirror_ip: 192.168.5.2
      vsa_mirror_netmask: 255.255.255.0
      vsa_mirror_pg: Mirror
      vsa_mirror_moref: Network:network-23
      esxi_hostname: 10.2.120.73
      esxi_datastore: DS-02
```

When I run the playbook I get the following error:

**TASK [vsa_deploy_config : Deploy VSAs on Center] *******************************************************************************
fatal: [auto-win1.lab.com]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/opt/ansible/roles/vsa_deploy_config/tasks/main.yml': line 10, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Deploy VSAs on Center\n  ^ here\n"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/opt/ansible/powershell.retry**

The first task using the template module interprets the item.vsa_hostname variable correctly, but the script module does not. Is the script module not capable of using with_items?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `with_items` for your script task:

```
- name: Deploy VSAs on Center                    # -\
  script: "files/{{ item.vsa_hostname }}.ps1"    #   \
  register: out                                  #   / This is task1
  when: target == "win_center"                   # -/
- debug: var=out                                 # -\
  with_items:                                    #   > This is task2
  - "{{ vsa_center }}"                           # -/
```

I guess you'd want to move debug to the very bottom:

```
- name: Deploy VSAs on Center
  script: "files/{{ item.vsa_hostname }}.ps1"
  register: out
  when: target == "win_center"
  with_items: "{{ vsa_center }}"

- debug: var=out
```

P.S. also there is no need to feed unnecessary nested list into `with_items`.

Answer (score 0):

just move the line `- debug: var=out` to the end of the file and it will work